# Action bar icon and label

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I want to use an app icon and action bar logo differently. For that, I am able to achieve that, but the concern is the while screen (Activity) is getting loaded and the label is also appearing with the action bar logo, but once the screen (Activity) loaded.

It vanishes as I want. Now I don't want to display that label while the activity is getting loaded. What should I do for that?

#### One more issue I am facing with the action bar logo is: it's not displaying on a large-screen mobile` (that is, [Sony Ericsson Xperia Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia_Z) (5-inch screen) and [Lenovo IdeaPhone K900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_IdeaPhone_K900), 5.5 inch). But for the Samsung devices, it's working fine. What's the issue?

Should I need to write a bunch of lines of code for that or is there a compatibility issue? How can I get rid from this problem?

Comment: I think this is a problem due to small or large icon size. See  http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html for correct icon size.'

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the app icon in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com..."
    android:theme="@style/Theme"></Application>
```

And for the action bar icon, create a theme. Something like:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is difference between this and earlier answer?? @peter mortensen